# Need a way to differentiate between white img and img with content

Tags: python, image, opencv, colors

I have plenty of pictures sliced from a big image. Some of them contain parts of an black sealing-ring but the most are purely white.

What I need is a way to identify all the images containing black parts because only they are relevant for my further questions.
There must be a smart way to do that, but I couldn´t find a simple way to do that.

For slicing etc. I used opencv so far

Thanks a lot

Comment: Just check the mean. Black images will have a mean near zero. White images will have a mean near 255.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could threshold the image [OpenCV threshold](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/miscellaneous_transformations.html?highlight=threshold#cv2.threshold)

```
im = cv2.imread('image.png', cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
thresh = 127
_,th1 =cv2.threshold(im,thresh,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
num_pixels = im.shape[0] * im.shape[1]
pixels_white = np.sum(th1)/255 # because everything above thresh is set to 255
percentage_white = pixels_white/num_pixels
absolute_below_thresh = num_pixels - pixels_white
```

You just have to find the right cutoff between black and white pixels `thresh`
And you have to find your own metric to determine how many white/black pixels you need to determine if if if purely white. You could use a percentage or an absolute threshold.